# Problems with scraping a website with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, discord.py

Basically, I am trying to scrape a trading website (https://rocket-league.com/) to find the most recent trade of the username you type in on discord.  To test, I was using this guy's account (https://rocket-league.com/player/Guuter).  After, the bot sends an embed containing a title, description (which works fine), but after add one field with a title of "Has:" containing the items he has and another field with a title of "Wants:" containing the items he has, which does not work currently.  The classes I am using are `rlg-trade__itemshas`  and `rlg-trade__itemswants`, which both contain their relevant items in plaintext under 3 separate fields which are colour, item and amount which I want in order respectively to after send.  However, sometimes there is no colour or amount specified, in which case it just sends the item.  Also, the amount of items varys - eg: 2 in has, 3 in wants or 1 in has, 5 in wants

I am quite stumped

Here is what I wrote:

```py
@bot.command()
async def rlgarage(ctx, arg):
 embed=discord.Embed(title="{}'s RLGarage Account".format(arg), description="https://rocket-league.com/player/"+arg)
 name = arg
 #arg = "Guuter"
 page = requests.get("https://rocket-league.com/player/"+arg)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
 hasitems = soup.find("div",class_="rlg-trade__itemshas")
 wantsitems = soup.find("div",class_="rlg-trade__itemswants")
 haslst=[]
 wantslst=[]
 for i in hasitems.find_all("a"):
   haslst.append(i.get_text(strip=True,separator=" "))
   embed.add_field(name="Has:", value=haslst,inline=False)
 for s in wantsitems.find("a"):
   wantslst.append(s.get_text(strip=True,separator=" "))
   embed.add_field(name="Wants:", value=wantslst, inline=False)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text' (line 112) - (wantslst.append)
```

Comment: `for s in wantsitems.find("a"):` is it correct?? what it should be if you are iterating over loop to find text.

Comment: what should it be instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should change find to `find_all()` while iterating `wantsitems`

```
@bot.command()
async def rlgarage(ctx, arg):
 embed=discord.Embed(title="{}'s RLGarage Account".format(arg), description="https://rocket-league.com/player/"+arg)
 name = arg
 #arg = "Guuter"
 page = requests.get("https://rocket-league.com/player/"+arg)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
 hasitems = soup.find("div",class_="rlg-trade__itemshas")
 wantsitems = soup.find("div",class_="rlg-trade__itemswants")
 haslst=[]
 wantslst=[]
 for i in hasitems.find_all("a"):
   haslst.append(i.get_text(strip=True,separator=" "))
   embed.add_field(name="Has:", value=haslst,inline=False)
 for s in wantsitems.find_all("a"):
   wantslst.append(s.get_text(strip=True,separator=" "))
   embed.add_field(name="Wants:", value=wantslst, inline=False)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: oh wow it acc works!! ty - mind if I ask one more question
Edit: Actually there are some issues

Comment: It seems to repeat each box like a single trade

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K4Jfxz1.png - shows message rn

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K4JgZBk.png - shows trade is one single trade - and not have multiple has and wants